# Python: null character breaking xml format

Tags: python, xml

I have some python code that processes input files and dumps certain fields from the input to XML files.  This code broke when passing a null character from input -- throwing an invalid token error:

```
def pretty_print_xml(elem):

    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent='    ')
```

This surprised me and I would like to know why it broke and what else might need to be sanitized from the input.  I thought only an XML meta character could throw this error and these are already being handled by minidom.

Comment: Waitaminute. You have an element, you're serializing it as a UTF-8 string, and then... what's the purpose of getting `minidom` involved?

Comment: If your goal is just to pretty-print, do you have `lxml` handy? I can give you that off the top of my head; would need to do some research for the standard-library ElementTree.

Comment: [To be clear -- `minidom` is really rather awful; it was among Python's first attempts at a standard-library XML module, and is still around for backwards compatibility, but that doesn't mean it's actually worth using].

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Haha, I cribbed the code from here https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html. Since doing so I have come to have doubts about it though. If you could recommend a better way, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. My first recommendation would actually be coming from the `lxml` world. Are you OK with installing additional dependencies?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yup. I will try that out. Many thanks.

Comment: ...that said, if you *really* have a NUL, what you're liable to get is this: `ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters`. Which is actually accurate: The XML standard doesn't allow NUL literals.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sadly there really are NUL characters. The error popped up only recently because none of the fields being written out to XML had ever contained one before. Now I know. :) Thanks for the link to the standard reference below. I will simply sanitize every field before passing it to any XML formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUL literals are not allowed in XML. See [the XML standard, version 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets):

> ### 2.2 Characters
>
> [Definition: A parsed entity contains text, a sequence of [characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#dt-character), which may represent markup or character data.] [Definition: A character is an atomic unit of text as specified by ISO/IEC 10646 [[ISO/IEC 10646]](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#ISO10646). Legal characters are tab, carriage return, line feed, and the legal characters of Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646. The versions of these standards cited in [A.1 Normative References](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-existing-stds) were current at the time this document was prepared. New characters may be added to these standards by amendments or new editions. Consequently, XML processors must accept any character in the range specified for [Char](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Char).]
>
> ```
> [2]       Char       ::=      [#x1-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF] /* any Unicode character, excluding the surrogate blocks, FFFE, and FFFF. */
> [2a]      RestrictedChar     ::=      [#x1-#x8] | [#xB-#xC] | [#xE-#x1F] | [#x7F-#x84] | [#x86-#x9F]
> ```

Note that `Char` is defined to allow (among other ranges) `\x01` through `\xD7FF` -- but **not** `\x00`.

---

By the way -- if your goal is pretty-printing, I'd suggest using `lxml.etree`. If [the `pretty_print=True` argument](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) on serialization calls doesn't work out-of-the-box, see [the relevant FAQ entry](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output).